# Silverlight, PostAsync returns no response

Tags: c#, silverlight, post, csrf, dotnet-httpclient

I've been trying to upload an image to my site using POST, the image is converted to base64 to transfer it.

Unfortunately I've stumbled upon an error with my Siverlight application. I've successfully gotten the base64 string of the image and now I want to upload it, this is the code I use to perform the POST request:

```
HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = hc.PostAsync("http://mywebsite.com/service.php", new StringContent("image=" + base64)).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Uploaded.");
}
```

Nothing happens when the second line is running, it just pauses completely, never jumps to the third line.

Since it's Async, I figured that I ought to prepend `await`, changing the line to:

```
var response = await hc.PostAsync("http://mywebsite.com/kurv.php", new StringContent("image=" + base64));
```

It gives me the error:

> Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>'

I've also checked up on silverlight, and it says that silverlight cannot access sites of which it is not allowed to, so I've added two files to the root of my site (http://mywebsite.com/): clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml.

The `clientaccesspolicy.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
                <domain uri="*"/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

and my `crossdomain.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Of course this is unsafe, but I'm only using this for the saking of testing right now, and getting my silverlight application to work.

Comment: Try adding Microsoft.Bcl.Async to enable async.  Not sure if it works on SL though.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use await, use .`ContinueWith`, something like what's below.  Silverlight doesn't play nice with blocking operations.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost/myproject/");

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var t = client.GetAsync("api/values");
        t.ContinueWith(p =>
        {
            if (p.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var users = p.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
                if (users != null)
                {

                }

            }

        });
```